# Using position: fixed – CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

Referring to this website – www.mrandmrsbutt.com – I'm trying to position the 'Upwaltham Barns' graphic at the bottom centre of the viewport, so no matter what size the viewport is the graphic will move with it and stay at the bottom.

I've tried adding the following custom CSS into my WordPress site, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
.fix{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
    }
<img src="http://www.mrandmrsbutt.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/banner-cta.png" class="fix"/>
```

Here is all my custom CSS at the moment:

```
#site-header.overlay-header{background-color:#fff;}
.menu-item a span:hover{color:#dfb5a9;}
#main-banner{
    background-image:url(http://www.mrandmrsbutt.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Top-Banner-Background.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:center center;
    height:100vh;
}
.centre{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}

#navigation-bar{
    background-image:url(http://www.mrandmrsbutt.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/navigation-background.jpg);
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height:48px;
}

p{margin-bottom:10px;}
.paper-background{
    background: #fff url(http://www.mrandmrsbutt.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/white-background.jpg) repeat top left;
}
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want `position: fixed;`, you're on the right path using `absolute`.

The problem is that the parent divs of what you're targeting aren't all 100% height of the viewport. You've set the outer-most parent to `height: 100vh;`, but it *really* needs applying to the inner `.vc_column_container` container (as it's using bootstrap based styles, and BS columns get position relative) - so your down arrow and graphic are being positioned based on that.

Try something like this:

```
#main-banner .wpex-vc-columns-wrap .vc_column_container {
    height: 100vh;
}
#main-banner .wpex-vc-columns-wrap .vc_inner::last-child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    bottom: 2.5%;
}
```

That should get you closer to what you're aiming for, be sure to include all vendor prefixes with `transform`, however if you're using something like Autoprefixer or Bourbon you'll already have this covered...

There's some "custom" styles in there I'm guessing you've added from a page-builder that might mess the position of the graphic/arrow up, remove the unnecessary padding if it's bugging out.

Good luck with the wedding :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change position:absolute to position:fixed in the .fix rule

```
.fix{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:50%;
}
```

This should send your graphic to the bottom of the viewport and left there even scrolling. The horizontal center could be a bit tricky, but you could try to use a fixed container with left and right set to 0.

```
.fixed-container{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
}
```

The previous rule sets the container to the bottom of the viewport and extends horizontally.

```
img.centered {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

This rule is applied to the image to achieve centered alignment inside the  container.

HTML code:

```
<div class="fixed-container">
     <img class="centered" src="..image..." />
</div>
```

I think this should do the trick.

Comment: I don't think he want's it fixed constantly even after scrolling, he wants it "fixed" to the parent, so it scrolls with it (ie. `position: absolute;`). _"no matter what size the viewport is ***the graphic will move with it*** and stay at the bottom"_